# Как создать текст с контуром на изображении RGB в буфере?

Tags: c++, графика, текст

Есть буфер с байтами RGB (раcжатый jpeg кадра с веб-камеры, без альфы, естественно). Нужно заменить часть этих байт (правый верхний угол) байтами переведенного в изображение текста с сохранением просветов в буквах, где он есть. То есть подписать кадр именем транслирующего клиента.

Заменить буфер по линиям со смещениями не проблема... Но **как создать такой текст в сырых байтах, с просветами и контуром?** ()

*PS: контур нужен, чтобы текст было видно как на тёмном участке кадра, так и на светлом - например, белый текст с чёрной или тёмно-серой обводкой.*

........

**В итоге, получилось так:**

```
void CollectFrames(){
    unsigned int OperationStartTime;
    // Создаём объект шрифта и контекст рисования
    HFONT font = CreateFont(15, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, RUSSIAN_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, "times");
    HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

    while(AllowOperations){
        OperationStartTime = GetTickCount();
        CameraFrameReady = false;

        RECT rect; // Создаём прямоугольник для текста
        rect.left = 0;
        rect.right = WebCam->GetFrameWidth();
        rect.bottom = WebCam->GetFrameHeight();
        rect.top = rect.bottom-15;

        LPBITMAPINFO lpbi = new BITMAPINFO;
        lpbi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        lpbi->bmiHeader.biWidth = WebCam->GetFrameWidth();
        lpbi->bmiHeader.biHeight = -WebCam->GetFrameHeight();
        lpbi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        lpbi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
        lpbi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

        unsigned char * buf = 0; // Указатель, где система выделит память при вызове CreateDIBSection
        HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hDC, lpbi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&buf, NULL, 0);
        delete lpbi;

        // Копируем в буфер hBitmap данные кадра (WebCam->CaptureFrame() тут возвращает unsigned char *)
        memcpy(buf, WebCam->CaptureFrame(), WebCam->GetFrameSize());
        // Источник данных тут больше не нужен, можно освободить память
        // Мой класс Camera сам управляет памятью, поэтому я тут ничего не удаляю

        // Выбираем объекты в контекст, задаём параметры и запекаем текст на изображении
        SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
        SelectObject(hDC, font);
        SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
        SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255,255,255));
        string Text = GetTime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S");
        DrawTextA(hDC, Text.c_str(), Text.size(), &rect, DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC); // Контекст больше не нужен

        // Выполняем все нужные операции с буфером hBitmap, после чего удаляем hBitmap (DeleteObject).
        CameraFrameBufferSize = WebCam->GetFrameSize();
        CameraFrameBuffer =(unsigned char *)realloc(CameraFrameBuffer, CameraFrameBufferSize);
        jpge::compress_image_to_jpeg_file_in_memory(CameraFrameBuffer, CameraFrameBufferSize, WebCam->GetFrameWidth(), WebCam->GetFrameHeight(), 3, buf, CameraCompressor);
        CameraFrame =string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(CameraFrameBuffer),CameraFrameBufferSize);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);

        CameraFrameReady = true;
        do{Sleep(1);}
        while(GetTickCount() - OperationStartTime < 33);
    }
    DeleteObject(font); // Объект шрифта тоже нужно удалить, когда он больше не нужен
}
```

Comment: Если вы пользуетесь виндой - то вам нужен getscanlines или что-то такое. В крайнем случае есть GetPixel - но он большой тормоз.

Comment: @nick_n_a, да, сервер под видну. Но как в принципе создать такой текст? Как обеспечить просветы в буквах? Изображение то без альфа-канала, и RGB текст тоже не будет "прозрачным"...

Comment: Под винду можно на GDI+ это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набросаю относительно простой пример для Windows, на чистом API получить текст с надписью в массиве байт RGB.

```
char* myFunct(int width,int height, char* text){
  HBITMAP bmp1 = CreateBitmap(width,height,24,0);
  HDC d0 = GetDC(0);
  HDC dc = CreateCompatibleDC(d0);      
  SelectObject(dc,bmp1);
  TextOut(dc,0/*x*/,0/*y*/, text, lstrlenA(text));
  // из microsoft      
BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;    
BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;

bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    
bi.biWidth = width;    
bi.biHeight = height;  
bi.biPlanes = 1;    
bi.biBitCount = 24/* тут было 32*/;    
bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
bi.biClrImportant = 0;

DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;

// Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper functions that 
// call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc 
// have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
char *lpbitmap  = (char*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,dwBmpSize);  // сюда можно поставить как массив, так и malloc или что вам нужно
// Gets the "bits" from the bitmap and copies them into a buffer 
// which is pointed to by lpbitmap.
GetDIBits(dc, bmp1, 0,
    (UINT)height /*высота экрана*/,
    lpbitmap,
    (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
DeleteObject(bmp1); // Освобождение
DeleteDC(dc);
ReleaseDC(0,d0);
return lpbitmap;
}
```

Надеюсь что это работает. Не проверял. Нижная часть взята тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Прелесть работы под виндой в том, что нужно правильно создать контекст DC и bitmap, потом связать их.
Дальше у вас два варианта, либо "вручную" рендерить текст, либо не удалять контексты и использовать TransparentBlt и подобное. На мой взгляд это на WinAPI сложно и будет страдать быстродействие.

Вручную будет в простейшем случае выглядеть где-то так (чёрный цвет-прозрачный, R!=0 G!=0 B!=0 вместо нуля можно использовать 1):

```
for (i=0;i<max;i++) if (buftext[i]!=0) bufdest[i] = buftext[i];
```

Comment: d2, я так понимаю, это d0? А под bmpScreen и hdcWindow что имеется ввиду?

Comment: да. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: это текущий dc, bmp. Если изображение (текста) вверх-тормашками, то перед `height`  в ф-ции `GetDIBits` можно поставить `-height` если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Что б сделать ободок можно, TextOut c SetTextColor использовать несколько раз.

Comment: Вы хорошо помогали в моих вопросах, я не могу не отписаться )) Как разберусь напишу...

Comment: В общем работает, но с просветами букв что-то не получается... Буду копать дальше сам. Спасибо!

Comment: Ещё прикол винды, пустые области винда заполняет белым `0xFF` (точнее 0xFFFFFF) а я вам посоветовал чёрный. Надо или всё закрасить чёрным, а потом печатать (и фон печати менять), но наверное проще таки белый сделать прозрачным. А текст чуть серее делать.  Вам нужно добится что б было 3-5 цветов в картинке.  Лучше всего что б ч/б,  А тогда либо чёрный назначить прозрачным, либо белый, либо одну из градаций. Покажите скрин тогда будет понятно что не то.

Comment: Возник ещё вопрос: не понятна строка "`DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;`". Что тут высчитывается и почему нельзя просто `width * height *3`??

Comment: Потому что microsoft прикольнулась, сделав выравнивание строк изображения по границе двойного слова (они это любят)